# Пропуск итераций Python

Tags: python, циклы

У меня есть такая задача: 
В первой строке вводится положительное число N, не превышающее 10000, определяющее количество входных данных. Во второй строке подается число M, по модулю не превышающее 1000000 (миллион). Далее в N строках вводится N целых чисел, по модулю не превышающих 1000000 (миллион). Необходимо найти количество чисел, больше М, при этом анализируя не все числа, а пропуская на каждом шаге на одно число больше. Таким образом нужно проверять числа со следующим порядковым номером: 1, (пропуск одного), 3, (пропуск двух) и т.д. 
Я написал такой код:

```
with open('6.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]

n, m = int(file[0]), int(file[1])
count = 0

for line in file[2:]:
    p = line.split()
    k = 0
    skip = 1
    for i in p:
        if k >= len(p):
            break
        if int(p[k]) > m:
            count += 1
        k += 1 + skip
        skip += 1
print(count)
```

Входные данные имеют такой вид:

```
6
32454
342343 
453453 
5645456 
324233 
666666 
777777
```

Если бы все корректно работало, код вернул бы число 3, так как остальные числа он бы пропустил. Однако код возвращает число 6, то есть он не пропускает итерации, как должен. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('6.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]

n, m = int(file[0]), int(file[1])
count = 0

i = 2
skip = 1
while i<len(file):
    if int(file[i])>m:
        count += 1
    i += skip
    skip += 1
```

Comment: Я сделал срез как [2:], потому что под индексом 0 и 1 - числа N и M соответственно. И мне нужно бежать не через один элемент, а каждый раз увеличивать шаг, то есть сначала через один, потом два, три и так далее

Comment: @Listopad02 исправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли